# PhpStorm Editor The screen blurred

Tags: phpstorm

Since fonts display before reason, download and install:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=zh_CN;

font rendering display problem solved,

comes a new problem, drag the window size when the editor windows screen blurred

---

OS ： OS X El Capitan
PhpStorm ： 9.0.2
PyCharm ： 4.5.4
Java -version ： 1.8.0_20

DEMO：
https://youtu.be/-h7At30CLls

Comment: I suggest trying version with **special bundled JDK** : https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/ -- look at "Using OS X 10 Yosemite? Get PhpStorm 9 with JDK 1.8" section. Also try **v9.5 EAP build** (with JDK): http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program

Comment: Thank you very much! Perfect solution! Stack Overflow is a great site!